# How does Django determine whether my database supports transactions?

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, innodb

On my development machine I can use `transaction.commit_on_success` and `transaction.commit_manually`, but on my production machine the decorators are ignored and Django behaves as if my database doesn't support transactions.  This happens both in my view functions and in trivial test functions I write in the Django shell:

```
>>> from django.db import transaction
>>> from myapp.models import *
>>> @transaction.commit_on_success
... def blah():
...   MyModel.objects.create(name="wazzup")
...   raise Exception
... 
>>> blah()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/python-environments/myenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 209, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<console>", line 4, in blah
Exception
>>> MyModel.objects.all()       
[<MyModel: wazzup>]
```

The same thing happens if I instantiate model objects and then call `save` on them rather than just calling `create` on the manager.  `commit_manually` fails in the same way.  In sum, it appears that `autocommit` is stuck in the on position.

But only on the production machine.  Everything works fine on my MacBook Pro.

Both environments are using MySQL with all tables running on InnoDB.  Django 1.4.3, Python 2.6.6.

I would appreciate any thoughts about what I might be doing wrong in settings.py, in my MySQL configuration, or anywhere else -- I am banging my head against the wall and am open to any suggestion at all.

Comment: Try doing a `SET GLOBAL general_log=1;` on both production and dev MySQL instances.  Then run the code in your question on both instances and then compare the mysql.log details.  Hopefully you'll spot a difference in log messages which will show you where the error lies.

Comment: Thanks Austin, I will try this and let you know if it tells me anything.

Comment: To answer the question of how Django determines whether your database supports transactions, take a look at the `django/db/backends/__init__.py` file's `BaseDatabaseFeatures` class's `supports_transactions` method: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/__init__.py

Comment: Thanks Nick -- I could have found that myself but sometimes asking on SO saves a bunch of time.  I am still confused though because I can't find any code (apart from Django's test code) that ever checks the value of BaseDatabaseFeatures.supports_transactions.  I.e. grepping is turning up nothing.  Are you aware of client code somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It's done like this:

```
from django.db import connection
if connection.features.supports_transactions:
    # We _do_ have transaction support.
else:
    # We _don't_ have transaction support.
```